Question regarding meaning of resultant of two vectors
I just learnt about the following formula to compute the resultant of a 2 vectors $\vec{a} \text{ and } \vec{b}$.
$$|\vec{a} \pm \vec{b}| = \sqrt{|\vec{a}|^2 + |\vec{b}|^2 \pm 2|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\cos(\theta)}$$
This formula is supposed to tell me the magnitude of the resultant of two vectors.
Then in a question i was solving information was given to me that when two vectors $\vec{P} \text{ and } \vec{Q}$ are added the magnitude of the resultant is $15$.
In the solution for the question the author squares both sides of the above formula i gave and obtains the following equation.
$$P^2 + Q^2 + 2PQ\cos(\theta) = 225$$
My question is that what does the value $225$ even mean i know the square root of it is the magnitude of the resultant, then what is the square of it?
And on the left side what does $P^2$ even mean, how do you square a vector?
Any help would be highly appreciated!

In all truth, vectors don't really have squares in the usual sense of the word, however, if $\vec P$ is a vector then we can take the inner product of that vector with itself:
$$\vec P\cdot\vec P=|\vec P|^2.$$
Where $|\vec P|^2$ is the square of the magnitude or resultant of the vector. For a sum of vectors, we can calculate the inner product with itself as:
$$\begin{align}
|\vec P+\vec Q|^2&=(\vec P+\vec Q)\cdot(\vec P+\vec Q)\\
&=\vec P\cdot(\vec P+\vec Q)+\vec Q\cdot(\vec P+\vec Q).
\end{align}
$$
Where the distributive property has been used, it is a simple exercise to verify the author's formula from here, given the knowledge that the value of the inner product can be defined geometrically as:
$$\vec P\cdot\vec Q=|\vec P||\vec Q|\cos\theta,$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors $\vec P$ and $\vec Q$.

the definition of $\textbf{p}^2$ is $\textbf{p}\cdot \textbf{p}$, so it's the square of its magnitude.Maybe this is what you are looking for?
